# Building Data Dictionary from model annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anybody have a way to generate a data dictionary from your models in a project?  You have your data type and and display annotation along with field name all in your models so it seems like you could generate a text/csv file with this information.

```
[Display(Name = "Type of Item")]
public string Type { get; set; }
```

Seems like this would be something people would use often if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection, call `Thing()` on your model class, get property parameters of interest and process as required in the loop.

```
public static void Thing<T>(this T model) where T : class 
{
  var t = typeof(T);

  var props =
    t.GetProperties()
     .Select(p => new { p, attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) })
     .Where(t1 => t1.attr.Length != 0)
     .Select(t1 => t1.p).ToList();

  foreach (var prop in props)
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```